# Inequalities inconsistency

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

There was an equation I was trying to solve.
I have converted the equation to basic terms for now.

\begin{align}
& -2x + 6 > 0 \tag{1} \\
\implies & -2x > -6 \tag{2} \\
\implies & x > 3 \tag{3}
\end{align}

Now, solving it another way, 
\begin{align}
& -2x + 6 > 0 \tag{4}\\
\implies & 2x - 6 < 0 \tag{5} \\
\implies & 2x < 6 \tag{6} \\
\implies & x < 3 \tag{7}
\end{align}

For the same equation, I am getting two different ranges of $x$. **Am I missing some rule/property**?

Comment: $x < 3$ instead:  the inequality reverses when you multiply through by a negative.

Comment: Actually I get the step you are referring to,but then too if I divide the equation with a (-2) in the equation -2x>-6 do have to flip the inequality sign? And are there some rules I can go through for inequalities.

Comment: I get going from $-2x+6>0$ to $2x-6 < 0$, that's fine.  Then you get $2x < 6$ and so $x < 3$, done.

Comment: The point you are saying is correct. But I need to know what's wrong in the first flow. I know that x<3 is correct. And my question here is -2x+6>0    ->.     -2x>-6  now I divide the equation with a (-2). So whenever I am dealing with a negative do I flip the sign is that the rule?

Comment: The thing wrong in the first flow is in my first comment.

Comment: Thanks Randall got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have $x<y$ then $ax < ay$ if and only if $a > 0$. If you multiply (or divide) by a negative number then the inequalities change direction. For example if I take $-3<-2$ and multiply by $-1$ then I would get $3 < 2$ which is evidently false. If I change the direction of the inequality though I would get $2<3$ which is correct.